# Merge de-batched message back to single message in BizTalk

Tags: c#, biztalk

After I receive a flat file, I am looping inside the orchestration, and filter some records. After the filter, I want to merge all the filtered record back together, in the same schema format. This is what i am doing:

Inside the loop:

```
var_xDocTemp=msg_card_file_single;
var_strMsg = var_strMsg + var_xDocTemp.OuterXml;
var_xDocTemp= System.Xml.XmlDocument 
var_strMsg= System.String
msg_card_file_single=filtered record (xml file)
```

After the loop:

```
//replace root node name and namespace in the string below with the correct rootnode name and namespace for XMSG message
var_strMsg = @"<Card xmlns:ns0=""http://namespacehere"">" + var_strMsg + "</Card>" ; 
var_xDocFinal.LoadXml(var_strMsg);
var_xDocFinal=System.Xml.XmlDocument
```

In the send port, when I gave  XML transmit, its giving an error:

> A message sent to adapter "FILE" on send port "SendPort5" with URI
>   "path" is suspended.   Error details: There was a failure executing
>   the send pipeline:    Reason: This Assembler cannot retrieve a
>   document specification using this type: "Card".

Comment: Is the 'filter' somewhat consistent?  Like always remove SomeID=500?  You definitely don't want to use strings for this.

Answer (score 0):

Supply the DocumentSpecNames on your XMLTransmit pipeline.

Here's a sample document specs name of your schema.

> BizTalk_Server_Project1.[SchemaTypeName], BizTalk Server Project1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d97c6c975378de4e

[image]